# Writing a function RGB to HSL in c++

Tags: c++

I have tried running this code on a website (coursemology) for submission of homework, but it keep giving me error.

I have tried to running this code on visual studio code without any problem

```
#include <math.h>
HSL rgb_to_hsl(int red, int green, int blue)
{
    int hue, sat, lum; // assign the correct values to these variables
    double max, min, red1, green1, blue1;
    red1 = red / 255.0;
    green1 = red / 255.0;
    blue1 = red / 255.0;
    if (red1 == green1 && green1 == blue1)
    {
        hue = 0;
        sat = 0;
        lum = 0;
    }
    else if (red1 > green1 && red1 > blue1)
    {

        max = red1;
        if (green1 > blue1)
        {
            min = blue1;
        }
        else
        {
            min = green1;
        }
    }

    else if (green1 > blue1)
    {

        max = green1;
        if (blue1 > red);
        {

            min = red1;
        }
        else
        {
            min = blue1;
        }
    }

    else
    {

        max = blue1;
        if (green1 > red1)
        {
            min = red1;
        }
        else
        {
            min = green1;
        }
    }
    lum = (max + min) / 2.0;
    if (lum < 0.5)
    {
        sat = (max - min) / (max + min);
    }
    else
    {
        sat = (max - min) / (2 - max - min);
    }
    if (max == red1)
    {
        hue = (green1 - blue1) / (max - min);
    }
    else if (max == green1)
    {
        hue = 2 + (blue1 - red1) / (max - min);
    }
    else
    {
        hue = 4 + (red1 - green1) / (max - min);
        hue = hue * 60;
    }
    if (hue < 0)
    {
        hue += 360;
    }

    lum = (int)round(lum);
    sat = (int)round(sat);
    hue = (int)round(hue);

    // *** Do not edit this line. It is to return 3 values together ***
    return (HSL){.hue = hue, .sat = sat, .lum = lum};
}
```

This is the error shown

> answer.cc: In function 'HSL rgb_to_hsl(int, int, int)':
>   answer.cc:171:9: error: expected '}' before 'else'
>            else
>            ^
>   answer.cc: At global scope:
>   answer.cc:177:5: error: expected unqualified-id before 'else'
>        else
>        ^
>   make: *** [answer.bin] Error 1

Comment: And where is this line 171 that is referred to in the error message?

Comment: you have a stray ; after if(). On side note, this code can be way simpler. Also, C++  do not define field-keyed initialization, it's C99 (is offered in C++20 though)

Comment: @yzt thats the problem, i couldnt find the line of problem as my code doesnt even reach line 171.

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie sorry i am abit new to this, so is it ok to explain clearly to me what should i do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a misplaced `;` after `if (blue1 > red)` in this part of the code:

```
else if (green1 > blue1)
{

    max = green1;
    if (blue1 > red);       // <<--- Here's the problem
    {
```